# MySQL query not working on Access

Tags: mysql, ms-access, vba

I have the following MySQL query:

```
INSERT INTO parts 
(part_id, source, user, decision, reason, date_messaged, date_suppress_message) 
VALUES ('IRUDHE3456','Escalation','john','fail','advertising','2015-07-01',NULL);
```

It inserts rows perfectly via MySQL Workbench. If I try to run this query via VBA in Access, nothing happens, I get no error message at all, nothing. And the row doesn't get inserted. The VBA looks like this:

```
DoCmd.RunSQL the_query_above
```

Any ideas of what I'm doing wrong? how does the syntax change in this case?

This is a linked table via ODBC, in case it matters, or is the issue more related to Access itself?

Comment: Is the *date_messaged* field's datatype Date/Time or text according to Access?

Comment: it is a DATE field in MySQL workbench, Access says Date/Time

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Find out why your `INSERT` fails with no error message.

Execute it with `CurrentDb.Execute` and its *dbFailOnError* option.  That combination will alert you to a key violation error which could otherwise cause a silent failure.

Also make sure `SetWarnings` is not switched off.  When it is off, Access suppresses information.  Make sure you get to see every possible tidbit of information which could aid your troubleshooting efforts.

```vb
'DoCmd.RunSQL the_query_above
DoCmd.SetWarnings True
CurrentDb.Execute the_query_above, dbFailOnError
```

I also suggest you revise the `INSERT` statement.  Enclose `[user]` in square brackets because it's a [reserved word](http://allenbrowne.com/AppIssueBadWord.html).  Since *date_messaged* is Date/Time datatype, use `#` characters instead of `'` quotes around the value you wish to insert there.

```sql
INSERT INTO parts 
(part_id, source, [user], decision, reason, date_messaged, date_suppress_message) 
VALUES ('IRUDHE3456','Escalation','john','fail','advertising',#2015-07-01#,NULL);
```